# Quick Books POS V6, SDK V3 - Using SDKTest "Can't connect to the database"

Tags: sdk, quickbooks

I'm running Quckbooks POS V6 (On Windows 7) and have just installed the QBPOSSDK3 to the system.  When I run the SDKTest it finds the POS and returns a connection string that looks right, but once I click on the "Begin Session" button I get an error stating "Can't connect to the database"

I've tried turning off my firewall, having Quickbooks running and not running - Nothing seems to change the error.

Any suggestions (Other than upgrade to a newer version of Quickbooks - which sadly isn't an option right now) would be gratefully appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have V6 anymore so I can't test, but I would try to see if you have the same problems with version 1.2 or 2.0 of the QBPOSSDK. If you get the same problem, then there might be a problem with the POS installation on that machine. I would also test the POS V6 installation on a different computer to see if you get the same results.